# In a SPFx Web Part, how can I extend JQuery with TypeScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

In order for a JQuery plugin called sliderkit to work I had to add a property in JQuery's interface.

I've added one line in it:

```
interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> extends Iterable<TElement> {
    sliderkit(options?: any, callback?: Function) : any;
```

Before doing that I was getting this error:

> Property ‘sliderkit’ does not exist on type ‘JQuery’

So I've found this article: [Typescript — Integrate jQuery Plugin in your Project](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc)
and it worked like a charm.

However, the change was done in this file:

> /node_monules/@types/jquery/JQuery.d.ts

Which sucks because everytime someone runs npm install it will overwrite the file.

**How can I achieve this without changing files inside node_mudules ?**

Comment: After you have done the changes in jquery file, you can remove its reference from `package.json` file temporarily (until development when you are running `npm install`). After that you can again add its reference back when you are done with adding dependencies using npm install

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed the [mentioned article](https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc), you can create a separated type definition file.

[image]

Below is a tutorial about how to add an external library to your SharePoint client-side web part.

- [Create a file in the your web part's folder called validator.d.ts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/add-an-external-library#example)